# What smarter way is to load a module inside makefile if not loaded already?

Tags: linux, makefile, csh, tcsh

In tcsh shell specifically a want to execute some commands using **make utility**. But to execute those commands I need to `"module load`" some modules first. How can I write the makefile to execute `module load a_module` if a_module is not already loaded? And also is there another smarter way I can execute `module` without executing ahead tcsh like this in Makefile?

```
load_a_module:
    /usr/bin/tcsh
    module load a_module
```

What I want my Makefile to do is something like this:

```
IF modules MOD1,MOD2... are not loaded
THEN module load modules MOD, MOD2 ...
DO_MY_STUFF
```

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a wrapper script - build.sh. Inside build.sh I'd set all the environment stuff needed by Makefile, and then, called the make itself.

Comment: I am not clear what you asking! Do you want to write a Makefile for make or do you want to write a shell script for tcsh? Or something which I not see?